# How to make HyperlinkButton navigate to an existing instance of a .xaml view?

Tags: silverlight

The following xaml snippets will cause a new instance of admin.xaml to be created every time it is navigated to.  Is there a way to make this always use the same instance or do I need to use something besides the HyperlinkButton?

```
 <HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="/Admin" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="Admin"/>


<Border x:Name="ContentBorder" >
    <navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Source="/Home" >
        <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
            <uriMapper:UriMapper>
                <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml"/>
            </uriMapper:UriMapper>
        </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
    </navigation:Frame>
</Border>
```

Comment: I'm not shore what are you expecting from this stuff. Do you want to add new value into `UriMapper` or just want to somehow navigate to .xaml page? Please add little more explanation.

Comment: I want to create my view once per application and navigate to it.   What else do you wish to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `NavigationCacheMode` property on the Page to `Required`.

[Page.NavigationCacheMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.navigationcachemode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)